# Deploy Express.js Status Ready But when I Open 404: NOT_FOUND

Tags: express, deployment, vercel

the vercer status says 'READY' but why when I open it I get a message

> 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID:
> sin1::69czg-1706252611358-fd6432e8d331

but when I tried it on localhost everything worked as it should anyone can help me?

this my code ./root/vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./app/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this my ./root/app/index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { sequelize } = require('./models/index');

const service = require('./configs/express');
const port = process.env.SERVICE_PORT;
global.__basedir = __dirname + '/..';

async function init() {
  service.start({ port });

  sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connect to Database');
  });
}

init();
```

and this my ./root/package.json

```
{{
  "name": "sikarad-be",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sikarad be",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "main": "./app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app/index"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "excel4node": "^1.8.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.27.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.90.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```